# Thread created but doesn't work accordingly

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I am facing a problem with a code I am writing but I really can't recognize what it's causing it, so a helping hand would be much appreciated. 
The case is simple

 --> giving number of threads as argument from the command line

 --> creating N threads , with parameter

 --> each thread says hello and it's parameter and exits
 
 So here is my code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* client_func(void *arg) {
    int myid = *((int *) arg);
    printf("hello!\n my id is %d\n",myid);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int i,j = 0;
    int N_cust = atoi(argv[1]);

    //creation of client threads
    pthread_t tid[N_cust];
    int err;

    for (i = 0; i < N_cust; i++){
        int *id = malloc(sizeof(*id));
        err = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &client_func,(void *) id);
        if(err !=0){
            perror("pthread_create() error");
            exit(1);
       }
       else{
           printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was waiting to get as a result the "hello" messages with the id of the thread but instead i get:

> $ ./proj1 3 5
>
> > Thread created successfully 
> >     Thread created successfully 
> >     Thread created successfully

I am new to threads, but from my understanding the thread is not executing at all . 
Any help in what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You allocate space for the `id` pointer to point at, but you never set it to any known value.  Your thread function also forgets to free the allocated memory it is given.  Your main program should probably also wait for the child threads to complete with `pthread_join()` before it exits (via `return 0;`).  Calling `exit()` — even indirectly by returning from `main()` — means that the process (and all the threads in it) are terminated immediately.  You could use `pthread_exit(0);` in `main()`, I believe, instead of `return 0;` and you might get your threads to run more.

Comment: I changed what you said and it worked . I believe the main problem was not including the pthread_join() function and not returning/exiting correctly. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778925/thread-created-but-doesnt-work-accordingly#comment98229533_55778925), you have a number of problems in your code:

- You allocate space for the `id` pointer to point at, but you never set it to any known value.
- Your thread function also forgets to free the allocated memory it is given.
- Your main program should probably also wait for the child threads to complete with `pthread_join()` before it exits (via `return 0;`).

Calling `exit()` — even indirectly by returning from `main()` — means that the process (and all the threads in it) are terminated immediately.  You could instead use `pthread_exit(0);` in `main()` instead of `return 0;` and you would get your threads to run to completion.

Here are two variants of your code with these problems fixed.  Variant 1 (`pthr41.c`) has the main thread exit with `pthread_exit(0);`.  Variant 2 (`pthr43.c`) has the main thread use `pthread_join()`.  There is a smattering of error detection added.

#### `pthr41.c`

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void *client_func(void *arg)
{
    int myid = *((int *)arg);
    printf("\nhello! my id is %d\n", myid);
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s numthreads\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int N_cust = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (N_cust <= 0 || N_cust > 1000)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: number of threads %s out of range 1..1000\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // creation of client threads
    pthread_t tid[N_cust];

    for (int i = 0; i < N_cust; i++)
    {
        int *id = malloc(sizeof(*id));
        *id = i + 1;
        int err = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, client_func, id);
        if (err != 0)
        {
            perror("pthread_create() error");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThread %d created successfully\n", i + 1);
        }
    }

    printf("\nMain thread exits\n");
    pthread_exit(0);
    //return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

It took a number of runs before I got this output, but this shows thread 4 finishing after the main thread:

```
$ pthr41 4

Thread 1 created successfully

Thread 2 created successfully

hello! my id is 1

hello! my id is 2

hello! my id is 3

Thread 3 created successfully

Thread 4 created successfully

Main thread exits

hello! my id is 4
$
```

#### `pthr43.c`

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void *client_func(void *arg)
{
    int myid = *((int *)arg);
    printf("\nhello! my id is %d\n", myid);
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s numthreads\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int N_cust = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (N_cust <= 0 || N_cust > 1000)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: number of threads %s out of range 1..1000\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // creation of client threads
    pthread_t tid[N_cust];

    for (int i = 0; i < N_cust; i++)
    {
        int *id = malloc(sizeof(*id));
        *id = i + 1;
        int err = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, client_func, id);
        if (err != 0)
        {
            perror("pthread_create() error");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThread %d created successfully\n", i + 1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N_cust; i++)
    {
        void *vp;
        int err = pthread_join(tid[i], &vp);
        if (err != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: error %d (%s) from joining thread %d\n",
                    argv[0], err, strerror(err), i + 1);
        }
        else
            assert(vp == NULL);
    }
    printf("All threads complete\n");

    //pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

```
$ pthr43 4

Thread 1 created successfully

hello! my id is 1

hello! my id is 2

Thread 2 created successfully

Thread 3 created successfully

hello! my id is 3

Thread 4 created successfully

hello! my id is 4
All threads complete
$
```